# Compare all fields from two tables and get unmatched records from the first table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables both have the same columns. I need to compare all the fields of the first table with the 2nd table. If any of the column value does not match then fetch that row of the Ist table. I need a MySQL query to do this. Please help me.

Comment: it is a one tome thing, you write all columns out. 'If you have to do it regularly with different tables, you can use information scheam to get all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.col1 <=> t1.col1 AND t2.col2 <=> t1.col2 AND ....
)
```

I use the operator `<=>` instead of `=` just in case you want to match `null`s also.
If this is not the case then use `=`.